# how to rotate and optimize properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am fairly new to programming, I have this game I'm working on
and I need help, I'm using unity.

I'm trying to make the obj rotate slightly towards left or right, but if I start pressing buttons at the same time, the rotations don't match. At the same time this code doesn't seem efficient, how can I fix this?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character2DController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float MovementSpeed = 1;



    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            RotateLeft();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown("d"))
        {
            RotateRight();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("a"))
        {
            ResetRotateLeft();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp("d"))
        {
            ResetRotateLeft();
        }




        void RotateLeft()
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
        }

        void ResetRotateLeft()
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        }





        void RotateRight()
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, -10);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Why are all your methods nested inside of `Update`? and why do you think it is inefficient? Except for the movement you should move the multiplactions inside ... currently you multiply vectors which is unnessary if you anyway use only one component (axis) of that vector ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character2DController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float MovementSpeed = 1;
    public float RotationSpeed = 10;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody = null;
    private float angle = 10;
    private float currentAngle = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        float movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float targetAngle = 0;
        if(movement > 0)
        {
            targetAngle = -angle;
        }
        else if (movement < 0)
        {
            targetAngle = angle;
        }
        transform.position += new Vector3(movement, 0, 0) * Time.deltaTime * MovementSpeed;
        currentAngle = Mathf.Lerp(currentAngle, targetAngle, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, currentAngle);
    }
}
```